# Change font size in epigraph

Tags: fontsize, epigraphs

I would like to reduce the font size of the epigraph on Part pages. When I write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape\filright}
  {\partname~\thepart:}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Connais-toi toi-meme.\par\hfill\textsc{Platon}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

The font size of the epigraph is 12pt:
[image: Test]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe an interaction with `titlesec`. What happens without loading it and redefining `part`?

Comment: I tried: it doesn't solve the problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `xpatch`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\epigraphsize}{\footnotesize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}
\xpatchcmd{\epigraphhead}{\begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}}{\begin{minipage}{\epigraphwidth}\raggedleft\epigraphsize}{}{}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
 {\Huge\scshape\filright}
 {\partname~\thepart:}
 {20pt}
 {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Connais-toi toi-même.\par\textsc{Platon}}

\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! A few more questions: 1) how can I change the spacing of the epigraph? I would like it in \singlespacing, whereas my document is in \doublespacing ; 2) for an epigraph with several lines, is it possible to get it justified?

Comment: 1) Load `setspace` (if not already done) and  add `\singlespacing` before the text of the epigraph (as an argument of `\epigraphhead`) 2) Remove `\raggedleft` from the patch – and perhaps add `\raggedleft` just for the author? (personal tast, of course).

Comment: I add `\singlespacing` in the xpatch command, after `\epigraphsize`, and I removed `\raggedleft`. The text is justified and the author name is automatically right justified. Thanks a lot, Bernard!